# struct file object of a file

Tags: files, filesystem, devices

Whenever a file is created in kernel space, struct file object instantiated. Type of that file does not matter. For device nodes, standard text files etc, a struct file object is created when a file is opened.

`What I am wondering is when this object is destroyed. Is the struct file object for that file destroyed when we call close() system call for that file?`

Extended Information:

`struct file` is a data structure of kernel. It cannot be used in user space c programs. Kernel defines an object from this data type to be able to perform some specific file operations. This object is created in kernel space when a user space program calls the system call `open()`.

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/fs.h

line 901

Comment: Don't have an answer, but seems like it  could be [__close_fd](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/6f0d349d922ba44e4348a17a78ea51b7135965b1/fs/file.c#L620) function, which receives  struct of files and sets the file descriptors to NULL

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful to receive some more specific information in order to answer properly. In what environment you are seeing this *struct file object*? Searching for *struct file object* in Google only points to this question.

But generally, a file descriptor in Unix-like operating systems can be created with the library function *open* which will use the kernel's system calls. The file descriptor can be released and deallocated with a call to library function *close* which will, again, use appropriate system calls and ensures that no resources will leak.

Comment: Okey, I will edit the question.